# What's required to let a domain send outbound emails from multiple domains?

Tags: dns, email, postfix

Let's say I have:

- 40 outbound emails to send
- main domain - `main_domain.com`
- 4 separate domains-workers with Postfix - `mail.my_postfix1.com`...`mail.my_postfix4.com`

**Goal:** send 10 emails via each of 4 worker-Postfix domains, on behalf of `main_domain.com`. In other words, let the main domain use 4 domains with Postfix to send outbound emails, equally so.

**Question**: How? What is it what should be set up in terms of DNS records?

Since MX records are required to receive the email, that is, for inbound emails, what is it that's required to send, outbound, emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to specify a `SPF` record for your domain handled by your servers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

All of your MTAs needs to appear in this records.

Additionally, it would help to add a `DKIM` record also, so that the big providers won't reject your outbound mails (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail).

Comment: One will ignore them anyway

Comment: `Additionally, it would help to add a DKIM record also` --> to which domain(s)? To the main one? Or to the 4 ones with MTA (Postfix)?

Comment: DKIM records need to be added to the Domain itself (main_domain.com). Then you would have to set up something like OpenDKIM (http://opendkim.org/) on every Server. Use this documentation to set up a DKIM milter for postfix: https://easydmarc.com/blog/how-to-configure-dkim-opendkim-with-postfix/. If you get stuck, pm me.

Comment: I don't understand. You first say `DKIM records need to be added to the Domain itself (main_domain.com).`. Then you say "Then you would " --> what does this "then" mean? "Then" after WHAT?

Comment: And, if they have to be added to the `main_domain`, why do you also say `on every Server.`? There's only *one* `main_domain` here, whereas there're 4 Postix MTA servers

Comment: Postfix needs to add DKIM records to outgoin mail on every server. So the DKIM configuration needs to be in the configuration of every postfix, and the keys need to be in DNS for the domain.